# How to calculate Vout from the MOSFET circuit

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis

This circuit diagram is given in my book :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4wGcg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

and said that from the above figure , they calculate \$ \frac{V_{out}}{V_p}  \$ while considering \$r_{o2}\$ and write down the answer is:

$$
\frac{V_{out}}{V_p} = \frac{1+g_{m2}r_{o2}}{1+\frac{r_{o2}}{r_{o4}}}
\approx\frac{g_{m2}r_{o2}}{1+\frac{r_{o2}}{r_{o4}}}
$$

No detail calculation was given and I tried my self but could not reach the solution. How can I do this kind of calculation?

can someone show me step by step solution for this so that I can do this kind of problems by my self in future. thanks in advance.

Comment: Is ro2 in the answer given the R_o2 from circuit, or M2 output resistance?

Comment: I have attempted to solve your circuit, but ended up with the answer divided by a factor of 2. Is the definition of gm used by your book author 2(Id/Veff)?

Comment: sorry , my mistake. ro2 is from the circuit (R_o2) . I edited the mistake.

Comment: @vicenteCunha , yeah . definition of gm is 2(Id/Veff) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output voltage Vout consists of two portions:

1.) Vout1 caused by the drain current Id of the transistor (voltage drop across r_o4),

2.) Vout2 caused (direct way) by the voltage divider between r_o4 and r_o2 .

**Calculation:**

1.) Transistor is in common base configuration with **Vout1=gm*(r_o2||r_o4)**

2.) **Vout2=Vp*[r_o4/(r_o4+r_o2)**

3.) The sum of both parts **Vout=Vout1+Vout2** gives the total signal output voltage. Divided by the input Vp we get the given gain expression (after some mathematical manipulations).

Comment: why two portion ? can you please explain the reason or provide me some link from where I can understand this.

Comment: The voltage Vp drives a current directly through r_o2 and causes a voltage drop across r_o4 (first portion). The other portion is a voltage caused  by the transistors output current Id (at the parallel combination of r_04 and r_o2). Remember that the transistor acts as a current source.